# Каждый пятый клик присваивать рандомное значение переменной Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я получаю значение `globalClick` из счётчика нажатий. Мне нужно чтобы на каждое пятое нажатие переменной `number` присваивалось рандомное значение. Но если счётчик остановится на 5ти, 10ти, 25 и т.д., то значение `number` обновляется постоянно, а мне нужно чтобы это выполнялось единоразово.

```
public int globalClick;
public int number;

void Update()
{
    globalClick = ClickCount.XP;

    if (globalClick % 5 == 0)
    {
        number = Random.Range(1, 5);
    }      
}
```

Comment: Так и сделайте присваивание рандомного значения при НАЖАТИИ. А сейчас у Вас проверка условия выполняется КАЖДЫЙ КАДР.

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение, спасибо

```
public class ClickCount : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] int clickes;
public Text Level;
public int Number;

public ClickCount( int clickes)
{
    this.clickes = clickes;
}

public void ButtonClick()
{
    clickes = clickes + 1;
    if (clickes % 5 == 0)
    {
        Number = Random.Range(1, 5);
    }
    
    

}
void Update()
{
     Level.text = clickes.ToString();
}

}
```